# woocommerce specific quantities for product

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a product that I want to allow to add to cart only in numbers that I allow.
The numbers arent exactly ordered so I want to create an array of the allowed quantities per product.
Is there a way to allow only the numbers I allow?

Comment: Put a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531738/set-min-quantity-for-some-product-categories-or-product-ids-in-woocommerce-3-3 on the first answer second step of message.

Don't forget change min for max.

Comment: I dont need min and max i need specific numbers

Comment: Aaahhh sorry! My bad english haha. But are you good in coding? with this code, you can easy create a value for each product ids and controle min/max at the same time for allow the button "add to cart".

Comment: I want to add a select box with values that are in an array. lets say the numbers are 5 8 10 13 15 18 and so on. I know how to create the array but what i dont know is how to only allow those numbers

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'control_product_qty_input', 20, 2 );
function control_product_qty_input( $args, $product ) {

    $settings = array('49' => 3, '48' => 10); // for product id 49 3 products set
    foreach ($settings as $k => $v) {
        if($k === $product->get_id()){
            $args['max_value'] = $v;
            $args['min_value'] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Note: Woocommerce hide the input number when min and max are same.

Note #2: This code'll work only on single product view.

EDIT: You can have multiple values in dropdown like this:
(But I still have a little problem with the existing input and I do not catch why. Try this code with me:)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'control_product_qty_input', 20, 2 );
function control_product_qty_input( $args, $product ) {

    $settings = array('49' => array(5, 8, 10, 13), '48' => array(2, 4));
    $options = '';

    $defaults = array(
        'input_name'    => 'quantity',
        'input_value'   => '1',
        'max_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', '', $product ),
        'min_value'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', '', $product ),
        'step'      => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', '1', $product ),
        'style'     => apply_filters( 'woocommerce_quantity_style', 'float:left; margin-right:10px;', $product )
    );

    $html = '<div class="quantity_select" style="' . $defaults['style'] . '"><select name="' . esc_attr( $defaults['input_name'] ) . '" title="' . _x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) . '" class="qty">';

    foreach ($settings as $k => $v) {
        if($k === $product->get_id()){
            foreach ($v as $v) {
                $options .= '<option value="' . $v . '">' . $v . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= $options . '</select></div>';

    echo $html;
}
```